# Make sequence array for edittext value

Tags: android, arrays, android-edittext

I have 270 `EditText`s. Now I want to get the value from each `EditText` and put it into a `String[]` concurrently and compare it for results. Unfortunately I can't do it. How can I achieve it?

One more thing I want to check if correct or not. If not correct I just get this correct answer in `EditText` which is wrong.

Comment: if edit text box in one layout then get all child  for (int i = 0; i < ll_projList_projectType.getChildCount(); i++) {
   
   if(ll_projList_projectType.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
    EditText edt = (EditText)ll_projList_projectType.getChildAt(i);
    str[i] = edt.getText().toString()
   }
  }

Comment: what is ll_projList_projectType?

Comment: This is layout which contain edit text box

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you have to iterate over all your `EditText` boxes and save its result in the string[]. To do this I recommend you to have this 270 `EditText` boxes inside a `ViewGroup` and then iterate over the childs of the `ViewGroup`. You can do something like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout); // The ViewGroup mentioned which should have the 270 EditText boxes inside
String[] myStringArray = iterateOverViews(layout);
```

Where `iterateOverViews(layout)` calls to this function:

```
public String[] iterateOverLayout(LinearLayout layout) {
    String[] ret = new String[270];
    for (int i = 0; i < 270; i++) {
        EditText box = layout.getChildAt(i);
        ret[i] = box.getText();
    }
    return ret;
}
```